# gsutil rsync between gzip/non-gzip local/cloud locations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rsync, gsutil

For change detection, can gsutil's rsync use the gzip'd size for change detection?

Here's the situation:

1. Uploaded non-gzip'd static site content to a bucket using cp -Z so it's compressed at rest in the cloud.
2. Modify HTML files locally.
3. Need to rsync only the locally modified files.

So the upshot is that the content is compressed in the cloud and uncompressed locally.  Can rsync be used to figure out what's changed?

From what I've tried, I'm thinking no because of the way rsync does it's change detection:

1. If -c is used, compare checksums but ONLY IF file sizes are the same.
2. Otherwise use times.

And it doesn't look like -J/-j impacts comparing the file size (the local uncompressed filesize is compared against the compressed cloud version which of course is FALSE) so -c won't kick in.  Then, the times won't match and thus everything is uploaded again.

This seems like a fairly common use case.  Is there a way of solving this?

Thank you,

Hans

Answer (score 0):

To figure out how rsync identifies what has been changed while using gsutils please check [Change Detection Algorithm](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#change-detection-algorithm).

I am unsure how do you want to compare between gzip non-gzip, but maybe [gsutil compose](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose) could be used to make that middle step while compare between files before being compressed.

Take into account that in [gsutils rsync's 4th limitation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#limitations):

> The gsutil rsync command copies changed files in their entirety and does not employ the [rsync delta-transfer algorithm](https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/) to transfer portions of a changed file. This is because Cloud Storage objects are immutable and no facility exists to read partial object checksums or perform partial replacements.